# jQuery keyup value does not change

Tags: jquery, html, keyup

```
var steps = 1;

$('#step_amount').keyup(function(){
    steps = $(this).val();
});

move(steps);
```

I have default value of steps 1, when I'm changing steps from input, move function still get 1.
how can I fix it?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Call `move` within the handler:

```
$('#step_amount').keyup(function(){
    steps = $(this).val();
    move(steps);
});
```

Else it will only be executed once, and that is with the default value of `steps`

Comment: In this case, if I don't change val, I can't run move()

Comment: Well, you'll have to figure a way to only run `move` once your `steps` get's updated.

Comment: @tymeJV I think you're misunderstand his question. The problem is that his closure keyup event isn't changing the steps value. He's realising this because his `move` function is getting 1 as argument. The fact that he hasn't supplied us with the `move()` implementation is misleading, but besides the point, I believe.

Answer (score -1):

When you say `var steps = 1;` you set step to a numeric type. However `$(this).val()` returns a string. So try using the following:

`steps = Number($(this).val());`

You keep getting 1 because when you try your code it throws an error and the value of steps never changes. Always check your console in your F12 menu for any errors whenever your code does not work.